# Loop through controls (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, loops, combobox

(Understanding of VB.NET: Intermediate)

I have 60 Comboboxes on a 10 tabs.

I want to add items to comboboxes as follows,

Comboboxes 1 to 30 should have items "a","b","c"

Comboboxes 31 to 60 should have items "d","e","f"

I tried to use following,

```
Dim cntrl as New Control
    For Each cntrl InMe.Controls            
       If (TypeOf cntrl Is ComboBox) Then                
       Combobox.Items.Add("a")            
       Combobox.Items.Add("b")
       Combobox.Items.Add("c")                        
       End If        
    Next cntrl
```

But how to add items to a specific comboboxes as mentioned above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways on how to do that. For example: create 2 list of controls and add all combo boxes that has to have items "a", "b", "c" to that first list, and all others to the second list. Then enumerate then and add corresponding items.

```
Dim abcCombos As List(Of ComboBox)
Dim defCombos As List(Of ComboBox)

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    abcCombos = New List(Of ComboBox)(New ComboBox() _
                  {ComboBox1, ComboBox2, ComboBox3})
    defCombos = New List(Of ComboBox)(New ComboBox() _
                  {ComboBox31, ComboBox32, ComboBox33})

End Sub

Private Sub PopulateABC()
    For Each cb as ComboBox in abcCombos
       cb.Items.Add("a")            
       cb.Items.Add("b")
       cb.Items.Add("c") 
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub PopulateDEF()
    For Each cb as ComboBox in defCombos
       cb.Items.Add("d")            
       cb.Items.Add("e")
       cb.Items.Add("f") 
    Next
End Sub
```